# My first Python project Tic Tac Toe v2

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

Hey guys this is my second attempt at a Tic Tac Toe game using the advice given in my first post: [My first Python project: Tic Tac Toe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210958/my-first-python-project-tic-tac-toe)

Again, just looking for advice on things I can improve. There is no classes because I have not really learned a great deal about OOP yet. I wanted to make sure I could use functions proficiently before I continued. I'm sure there is a way to loop the if statements in check_win(), but I have not figured it out yet.

```
def num_to_coord(num):
# 0-index num
    num -= 1
    coord = []
    while True:
        curr_coord = num % 3
        coord.append(curr_coord)
        if len(coord) >= 2:
            break
        num -= curr_coord
        num //= 3
    return coord


def change_symbol(the_symbol):
    if the_symbol == 'x':
        the_symbol = 'o'
        return the_symbol
    if the_symbol == 'o':
        the_symbol = 'x'
        return the_symbol


def get_position():
    position = int(input("Enter a position: "))
    return position


def check_position(the_position, the_taken_positions):
    if the_position in the_taken_positions:
        return True
    if the_position not in the_taken_positions:
        return False


def draw_position(location, the_symbol, the_game_board):
    coord = num_to_coord(location)
    the_game_board[coord[0]][coord[1]] = the_symbol
    for y in range(3):
        print(add_sep('|', [the_game_board[x][y] for x in range(3)]))


def add_sep(sep, lst):
    """Adding | to board"""
    output = sep
    for i in lst:
        output += i + sep
    return output


def check_win(the_game_board):
    if the_game_board[0][0] == 'x' and the_game_board[1][0] == 'x' and the_game_board[2][0] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[0][0] == 'o' and the_game_board[1][0] == 'o' and the_game_board[2][0] == 'o'):
        return True
    if the_game_board[0][1] == 'x' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'x' and the_game_board[2][1] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[0][1] == 'o' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'o' and the_game_board[2][1] == 'o'):
        return True
    if the_game_board[0][2] == 'x' and the_game_board[1][2] == 'x' and the_game_board[2][2] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[0][2] == 'o' and the_game_board[1][2] == 'o' and the_game_board[2][2] == 'o'):
        return True
    if the_game_board[0][0] == 'x' and the_game_board[0][1] == 'x' and the_game_board[0][2] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[0][0] == 'o' and the_game_board[0][1] == 'o' and the_game_board[0][2] == 'o'):
        return True
    if the_game_board[1][0] == 'x' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'x' and the_game_board[1][2] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[1][0] == 'o' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'o' and the_game_board[1][2] == 'o'):
        return True
    if the_game_board[2][0] == 'x' and the_game_board[2][1] == 'x' and the_game_board[2][2] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[2][0] == 'o' and the_game_board[2][1] == 'o' and the_game_board[2][2] == 'o'):
        return True
    if the_game_board[0][0] == 'x' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'x' and the_game_board[2][2] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[0][0] == 'o' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'o' and the_game_board[2][2] == 'o'):
        return True
    if the_game_board[0][2] == 'x' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'x' and the_game_board[2][0] == 'x' or \
        (the_game_board[0][2] == 'o' and the_game_board[1][1] == 'o' and the_game_board[2][0] == 'o'):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def intro():
    intro_board = [['1', '4', '7'], ['2', '5', '8'], ['3', '6', '9']]
    print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe")
    print("You can pick location by identifying the position on the board. (There are 9 positions)")
    print("The player who plays first will be using 'x' and the second player will be using 'o'.")
    for y in range(3):
        print(add_sep('|', [intro_board[x][y] for x in range(3)]))


def main():
    game_board = [[' '] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
    taken_positions = []
    symbol = 'x'
    num_moves = 0
    win = False
    intro()
    while num_moves < 9 and not win:
        position = get_position()
        taken = check_position(position, taken_positions)
        if taken:
            print("Position taken! Try again.")
        else:
            draw_position(position, symbol, game_board)
            taken_positions.append(position)
            symbol = change_symbol(symbol)
            num_moves = num_moves + 1

        win = check_win(game_board)
        if win:
            print("We have a winner!")
            break

    if num_moves == 9 and not win:
        print("WOW! You guys are good! DRAW!!!")


# MAIN
main()
print("Thanks for playing! Exiting")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## magic numbers

I see the value 3 (and 9) in your code when it refers to the board size. It is best to prevent such magic number, and either replace them with variables, or with constants

```
BOARD_SIZE = 3
```

## `num_to_coord`

you can use `divmod` to calculate the quotient and remainder of a modulo division in 1 step, so `num_to_coord` gets reduced to:

```
def num_to_coord(num):
    """calculates the coordinate of a 1-indexed position number

    Examples
    --------
    >>> num_to_coord(1)
    (0, 0)
    >>> num_to_coord(3)
    (0, 2)
    >>> num_to_coord(4)
    (1, 0)
    """
    return divmod(num - 1, BOARD_SIZE)
```

The effect is a 90° rotation of the board

## multi-line strings

Python has multiline string literals, so your welcome ca

```
def intro():
    welcome_message = """
    Welcome to Tic Tac Toe
    ______________________
    You can pick location by identifying the position on the board. (There are 9 positions)
    The player who plays first will be using 'x' and the second player will be using 'o'.
    """
    print(welcome_message)
    intro_board = """
    |1|2|3|
    |4|5|6|
    |7|8|9|"""
    print(intro_board)
```

## State

to separate state and representation, I would use an `enum.Enum` to keep the state of a board position

```
import enum
class Position(enum.Enum):
    EMPTY = " "
    PLAYER_1 = "x"
    PLAYER_2 = "o"
```

then later on, you can define the game_board as `game_board = [[Position.EMPTY] * BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]`

This allows you to check whether there are still open positions in this way:

```
def check_board_open(the_game_board):
    """checks whether there are still open positions in the board"""
    return any(Position.EMPTY in row for row in the_game_board)
```

instead of having to keep a count of how many moves have been done

and drawing the board becomes:

```
def format_row(row, separator="|"):
    return (
        separator
        + separator.join(position.value for position in row)
        + separator
    )


def draw_board(the_game_board, separator="|"):
    return "\n".join(format_row(row, separator) for row in the_game_board)
```

In your code, you also put changed the board in the method to draw the board, which is a serious violation of the separation of concerns.

## `taken_positions`

you define `taken_positions` as a list, but the order is unimportant, and the main goal is check for containment. A `set` is a more suited collection for this purpose.

## `check_position`

```
def check_position(the_position, the_taken_positions):
    if the_position in the_taken_positions:
        return True
    if the_position not in the_taken_positions:
        return False
```

can be simplified to

```
def check_position(the_position, the_taken_positions):
    return the_position in the_taken_positions
```

and then dropped altogether to make it inline

## user input

You trust your user to input a valid number. This can be made more robust, and integrate the check whether the position is empty

```
class GameEnd(Exception):
    pass


def get_empty_position(the_game_board):
    max_position = BOARD_SIZE ** 2
    while True:
        user_input = input(f"Enter a position [1-{max_position}]: (q to quit)")
        if user_input.lower() == "q":
            raise GameEnd()
        try:
            position = int(user_input)
            if not 0 < position <= max_position:
                continue
            x, y = num_to_coord(position)
            if the_game_board[x][y] != Position.EMPTY:
                print("Position taken! Try again.")
                continue
            return x, y
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

This keeps asking for input until a valid, empty position is given, or `"q"`.
If the user wants to end the game, this raises a `GameEnd` exception.

You also don't need the `taken_positions`, since checking whether the position is taken is done here immediately, and directly compared to the game board instead of a second data structure.

## Win situations

@feelsbadman is correct that you can decouple the different rows, columns and diagonals to check for a win condition, but I  think the way he implements it can be improved. For tips on looping, check the great talk: ["Looping like a Pro"](https://archive.org/stream/pycon-2017-looping) (video on Youtube)

Instead of looping over the indices, you can loop over the rows or columns, and then see whether there is a sole player in that row or column.

To see whether there is a winner in a row, columns or diagonal, you can use this:

```
def get_winner(row):
    row_set = set(row)
    if len(row_set) == 1 and Position.EMPTY not in row_set:
        return row_set.pop()
```

This returns the winner if there is one, or None if there isn't

```
def check_win_horizontal(the_game_board):
    for row in the_game_board:
        winner = get_winner(row)
        if winner:
            return winner
    return None
```

to check vertical, you can transpose the board with `zip(*the_game_board)` so a separate vertical method is unnecessary.

For the diagonal, you can define 2 diagonals:

```
diagonal1 = {the_game_board[i][i] for i in range(BOARD_SIZE)}
diagonal2 = {the_game_board[i][-(i + 1)] for i in range(BOARD_SIZE)}
```

and then check them like this:

```
def check_win_diagonal(the_game_board):
    diagonal1 = {the_game_board[i][i] for i in range(BOARD_SIZE)}
    diagonal2 = {the_game_board[i][-(i + 1)] for i in range(BOARD_SIZE)}
    winner = get_winner(diagonal1) or get_winner(diagonal2)
    return winner
```

The general method to check whether there is a winner then simply is:

```
def check_win(the_game_board):
    return (
        check_win_horizontal(the_game_board)
        or check_win_horizontal(zip(*the_game_board))
        or check_win_diagonal(the_game_board)
    )
```

## `change_symbol`

can be simplified to

```
def change_symbol(the_symbol):
    symbols = {"x": "o", "o": "x"}
    return symbols[the_symbol]
```

But this can also be done differently:

In the `main` method, you define the players as a `itertools.cycle` of `(Position.PLAYER_1, Position.PLAYER_2)`. To get the next player, you just do `player = next(players)`

changing the board is then as simple as

```
    x, y = get_empty_position(game_board)
    game_board[x][y] = player
```

## main

```
def main():
    game_board = [[Position.EMPTY] * BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
    players = cycle((Position.PLAYER_1, Position.PLAYER_2))
    intro()
    while check_board_open(game_board):
        player = next(players)
        print(f"Player {player.value} to move")
        x, y = get_empty_position(game_board)
        game_board[x][y] = player
        print(draw_board(game_board))
        winner = check_win(game_board)
        if winner:
            return winner
```

## main guard

Best put the code that should be run as a script behind a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, so you can import this file with a minimum of side effects

```
def ask_retry():
    user_input = input("press ENTER to continue, q, then ENTER to quit")
    return not user_input.lower() in {"q", "quit"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    retry = True
    while retry:
        try:
            winner = main()
            message =  f"{winner.name} won!" if winner else "WOW! You guys are good! DRAW!!!"
            print(message)
            retry = ask_retry()
        except GameEnd:
            print("Thanks for playing! Exiting")
            retry = False
```

## testing

By separating the methods like this, you can easily test them with unit tests. For code like this, which is 140 lines long, you can easily test it by hand, but if you want to incorporate changes later, like varying board sizes, a working, complete test suite will be a great help in spotting bugs.

Comment: Great stuff, going to take me a while to understand all this.

Answer (score 2):

You could begin with `win` checking. The way you have done it works fine. But what if you were to resize the board? lets say `5x5`? You would need to write lots of if/else statements to check for winning cases.

Now, instead of using loads of `if/else` statements to look for winning cases you could use `for` loops to look trough `rows`, `columns`, and `crosses` as shown here:
[image]

Here is an example of what I am talking about (you can use this if you wish so):

this one is for `column` checking (top-down)

```
# check columns
# symbol can be x or o
def checkCol(symbol, board):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board)):
            if board[j][i] == symbol:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
        if counter == len(board):
            break
    return True if counter == len(board) else False
```

and this is for `row` checking (left-right)

```
# check rows
# symbol can be x or o
def checkRow(symbol, board):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board)):
            if board[i][j] == symbol:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
        if counter == len(board):
            break
    return True if counter == len(board) else False
```

Positive cross:

```
#prositive cross (top left to bottom right)
def checkCrossPositive(symbol, board):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if board[i][i] == symbol:
            counter+=1
        else:
            counter = 0
    return True if counter == len(board) else False
```

Negative cross:

```
# negative cross (top right to bottom left)
def checkCrossNegative(symbol, board):
    counter = 0
    j = len(board)-1
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if board[i][j] == symbol:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 0
        j-=1
    return True if counter == len(board) else False
```

Here's how it can be used:

```
def check_win(board):
    return \
        (checkRow('x', board) or checkRow('o', board) )\
    or  (checkCol('x', board) or checkCol('o', board))\
    or  (checkCrossPositive('x', board) or checkCrossPositive('o', board))\
    or  (checkCrossNegative('x', board) or checkCrossNegative('o', board))
```

**EDIT:**

Avoid manually placing numbers here and there such as in

```
if num_moves == 9 and not win:
```

instead of that you could have it in a "constant" variable.
(I know `python` doesn't have `constant` but just for the sake of best-practice)

```
if num_moves == MAX_MOVES and not win:
```

---

**EDIT (Explanation for column checker):**

**Part 1**

Usually when we iterate over a two dimensional array we use `i` and `j` as `X` and `Y` where `i=Y` and `j=X`
let's say we have a two dimensional array as this:

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
]
```

If we iterate over this array the usual way we'd get `1,2,3,4,5` & `6,7,8,9,0`
as output because the `Y-axis ( i )` represents indexes of inner arrays (those that contain numbers 1,2,3 ...).
First (inner-)array has index `0`, the second one has `1` and so on it goes.

This way we are iterating `row => col1, col2, col3, ...` meaning `i => j1, j2, j3, ...` but since we need to
look for columns rather than rows we need to switch the usage of `i` and `j`
where, for example, to access number `1` in the first array we would have the following: `array[i][j]` or `array[0][0]`
but in this case we have to use it as `array[j][i]` *(<- notice that i switched them)*.

Now when we have switched the index (representors?) we would get an output as this:
`1,6` & `2,7` & `3,8` & `4,9` & `5,6`

Here is a "GIF" to animate the concept behind this:
https://i.imgur.com/4HqLpcD.mp4

**Part 2**

As you might have noticed there is a `counter` variable initialized with `0` at the very beginning of the code.
The purpose of this `counter` is to keep track of how many of `_symbol_` we have found while iterating of columns.

Inside the second loop there's a code block:

```
if board[j][i] == symbol:
    counter += 1
else:
    counter = 0
```

The purpose of this part is to increase our `counter` variable by `1` if a symbol is found. if not it is re-set back to `0`.
This is because for someone to win, the whole column would have to be of the same symbol, let's say symbol `o`
and if any section in the column does not match our symbol `o` then it means `player-o`
can not win because in order for him to win all of the sections in the current column (index `0` to `4`)
would have to be of the same symbol.

When the first column has been scanned, we must check whether we have found enough symbols to call it a win or not.

```
if counter == len(board):
    break
```

Since our board is a square we can safely compare our counter to the length of our board.
Why? Because there are as many indexes(`0` to `4`) as the length(`5`) of our board.
So when I have filled the first column with symbol-`o` there will be exactly 5 `o`s in that column.

When the above statement is true; main loop will break and then a boolean value is returned:

```
return True if counter == len(board) else False
```

As obvious as it is: When counter is equal to the length of our board `True`(won!) is returned otherwise `False` (didn't win)

Comment: Thank you for the advice on how to loop through the check_win. I have to admit though, looking at the code, I'm pretty confused. Can you explain the code in a bit more detail? If not, no problem.

Comment: @BobPage UPDATE: Added explanation for column checking (will add other explanations as soon as possible) btw, let me know if you have trouble understanding anything